# Get part out of string based on a specific value

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
SET PATH=\\dc01\intern\Product\NightlyBuild\Reg\Reg_20171207.1\out\site
OR
SET PATH=\\dc01\intern\Product\Release\ex\17.12\site
```

Now I want to get the following values out of the variables:

```
PATH_trimmed = Reg\Reg_20171207.1
OR
PATH_trimmed = 17.12
```

So for each path a different section should be taken out of the variable. So for example I need a method that search for the word: "**NightlyBuild**" or "**Release**" in order to retrieve the desired value. I tried to do this by using left string methods like:

```
%path:~0,4%
```

But that does not work. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to parse the `PATH` string:-

```
@echo off
rem SET PATH=\\dc01\intern\Product\NightlyBuild\Reg\Reg_20171207.1\out\site
rem SET PATH=\\dc01\intern\Product\Release\ex\17.12\site
rem for /f "tokens=4-6 delims=\" %%f in ("%path%") do echo %%f:%%g:%%h
for /f "tokens=4-6 delims=\" %%f in ("%path%") do (
    if %%f==NightlyBuild set PATH_trimmed=%%g\%%h
    if %%f==Release set PATH_trimmed=%%h
)
rem echo PATH_trimmed=%PATH_trimmed%
```

This avoids the use of external programs: it splits `PATH` at each `\` into separate variables, ignoring blank fields, so the first significant field is `dc01`, but only the fourth to sixth fields are extracted, to `f`, `g` and `h` respectively.

By comparing `%%f`, the appropriate value is set into the `PATH_trimmed` variable. The technique can easily be extended to other `PATH` formats.

The commented-out lines were used for testing purposes.

Comment: awesome that is exactly what I want with a clear explanation! Thank you very much!